# How to call set before configureFieldMetadata in BridgeClass

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I have the following BridgeClass and i need that `configureFieldMetadata` to be executed after the `set` method.
But by default it's `configureFieldMetadata` executed first.
Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class AdditionalAttributesBridge implements 
        MetadataProvidingFieldBridge{
  @Override
  public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, 
      LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
    Set<AdditionalAttribute> attributes = (Set<AdditionalAttribute>) 
     value;
    for (AdditionalAttribute a : attributes) {
        //some code
    }
 }

   @Override
   public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder 
     builder) {
    //ToDo
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`configureFieldMetadata` is executed on bootstrap, while `set` is executed at runtime, when indexing.

So no, this is not possible.

You might want to consider why you need `set` to be called before `configureFieldMetadata`. I guess you initialize something in the `set` method based on the parameters, but I don't know what sort of information you would have in `set` that you could possibly need in `configureFieldMetadata`... ?

Comment: Thanks @yrodiere for your response. In the set method i've a list of attributes that i want use in configureFieldMetaData.

Comment: Ok. So you're getting metadata from the object itself. Is there any other way you could retrieve this metadata? For example from an injected bean? Recent versions of Hibernate Search support instantiating bridges through Spring/CDI, and this enables the use of `@Inject`/`@Autowired` in your bridge. Make sure to give your bridge the prototype/dependent scope, though; see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-bridge-dependency-injection .

Comment: Another possibility, if you gathered metadata through reflection, is to ask Hibernate Search to give you the type of the property bound to the bridge; see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_type_aware_bridge.

Comment: I tried to retrieve the data that i want to use inside configureMetaData method, by autowiring the repository, but it doesn't work. How can i enable @Autowired inside Bridge ?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is hardly enough information to answer your question. I suppose you got a circular dependency: your repository depends on Hibernate ORM, which depends on Hibernate Search, which depends on your bridge, which depends on your repository. [This](https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring) seems to indicate that adding `@Lazy` on your injected field may solve a circular dependency.